# (MISSING)TILLER: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I created a Single node Kuberenetes cluster using minikube and I installed helm on that. But I am getting issue while executing helm ls and helm install commands. This is this issue I am facing:

`"Get http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps?labelSelector=OWNER%!D(MISSING)TILLER: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused".`

These are pods are running on kube-system namespace

```
ubuntu@openshift:~$ kubectl get po -n kube-system
NAME                                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default-http-backend-vqbh4              1/1       Running   1          6h
etcd-minikube                           1/1       Running   0          6h
kube-addon-manager-minikube             1/1       Running   4          1d
kube-apiserver-minikube                 1/1       Running   0          6h
kube-controller-manager-minikube        1/1       Running   0          6h
kube-dns-86f4d74b45-xxznk               3/3       Running   15         1d
kube-proxy-j28zs                        1/1       Running   0          6h
kube-scheduler-minikube                 1/1       Running   3          1d
kubernetes-dashboard-5498ccf677-89hrf   1/1       Running   8          1d
nginx-ingress-controller-tjljg          1/1       Running   3          6h
registry-wzwnq                          1/1       Running   1          7h
storage-provisioner                     1/1       Running   8          1d
tiller-deploy-75d848bb9-tmm9b           1/1       Running   0          4h
```

If you have any idea please help me. Thanks

Comment: I found the solutions for this issue: kubectl --namespace=kube-system edit deployment/tiller-deploy and changed automountServiceAccountToken to true

Comment: For me that worked for version v0.25.2 of minikube, but not for v0.26.1.
See https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/issues/3460, https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/issues/3816